# Magento: different URLs for different StoreViews?

Tags: magento

in our Magento Shop we have 2 StoreViews for 2 different languages. Since both StoreViews uses the same URLs, only one Storeview is beiing indexed by Google in the correct country. Is it possible to automatically change the URLs of the one StoreView to make it unique for both StoreViews?

Thanks,

Toby

Answer (score 2):

You can change your store url and can have a different url for different stores.
Go to System -> configuration -> Select the Store view in the drop down (Default config) -> Go to Web -> Uncheck the Use default option and Enter the URl for the Store view..

Hope this helps you